# Nest API, On button click, run PHP function which changes data, then reload the data

Tags: php, html, ajax, nest

I have a website interfacing my Nest Thermostat.  I am trying to have HTML Up/Down buttons trigger a function that takes the target temperature of a thermostat, increments or decrements by one degree, adjusts the thermostat, and then displays the newly set temperature of the thermostat.

I can make it work (without AJAX) but it isn't pretty and appends 'tempUp/Dn=1' tags to my sites URL which messes things up.   Shown below is the current setup.   How can I use AJAX with this setup, so I can browse index.php and increment/decrement the temperature without leaving index.php?

I am assuming I need a little something like this, but I don't know where to fit it in:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "something.php",
   success: function(msg){
      alert( 'something' );
   }
 });
```

**index.php:**

Main portal for my website.  Does lots of stuff.   Only showing portion where is brings in my thermostat plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        // Load at thermostat 
        $.ajax({
            url: "./thermostat/thermostat.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data){
                $("#thermostat_div").html(data);
            }
        })
 });
 </script>
 <div id=thermostat_div>
     Loading the thermostat...
 </div>
```

**thermostat.php:**

Shows the target temp from the thermostat.  Also show up and down buttons intended to increment or decrement the temp.

If I load this page in my browser directly, it works.  It works by adding "&tempUp=1" or "&tempDn=1" the url and reloading the page.  But, when I load my main index.php, the buttons fire when click, but the temperature is not updated.   I need something so I can load index.php, click the buttons, run the proper increment/decrement function, then somehow refresh the thermometer_div to show the new set temperature without crap added to the URL.

```
     <?php 
     // Import the function to adjust the target temp
     include '/var/www/thermostat/functions.php

     // Display the temp the thermostat stat is set to 
     echo "<div class='targetTemp'>".$targetTemp."</div>"; 

    if($_GET['tempDn']){
        $targetTemp = $targetTemp - 1;
        $newTemp = '{"target_temperature_f": ' . $targetTemp . '}';
        changeTemp($newTemp);
    }
    if($_GET['tempUp']){
        $targetTemp = $targetTemp + 1;
        $newTemp = '{"target_temperature_f": ' . $targetTemp . '}';
        changeTemp($newTemp);
    }

    ?>

    <button class="btndn orange" type="button" onClick='location.href="?tempDn=1"'>ᐁ</button>
    <button class="btnup orange" type="button" onClick='location.href="?tempUp=1"'>ᐃ</button>
```

**functions.php:**

```
<?php
function changeTemp($changeTempTo) {
    include '/var/www/config.php';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/secretcode",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $changeTempTo,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: Bearer ".$nestAccessToken,
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "content-length: ".strlen($changeTempTo)
        ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    }
}


//Get all the other status off the thermostat
include '/var/www/config.php';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/secretkey",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "client_id=".$nestClientID."&client_secret=".$nestClientSecret."&grant_type=authorization_code&code=".$nestAuthCode,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Bearer ".$nestAccessToken,
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    $parsed_json = json_decode($response);
    $targetTemp = $parsed_json->{'target_temperature_f'};     
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do it this way:

in your php file handle the things like this:

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
        $action = $_POST["action"];
        switch ($action) {
            case 'update':
                if (isset($_POST["request"])) {
                    $request= $_POST["request"];
                    if ($request == "temperature") {
                       //do your curl here and fill your response then send it
                       echo json_encode($response);
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

Where action is a command you want to do and parameter something to trigger a specific utility function

then in your ajax:

```
function getInfo(action,request) {
   return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getInfo.php",
        data: {action:action, request: request}
    })

}
```

call it like this on your click:

```
$("#myButtonId").on('click',function(){
getInfo('update','temperature').done(function(response){
var data=JSON.parse(response);
if (data != null) {
//fill your forms using your data e.g
$("#yourInput").val(data.temperature);
}
})

})
```

Hope it helps